# What is name of these furniture wheels?

Tags: furniture

Here is the picture. There are multiple wheels in one place. I need something that has three wheels to spread the weight so there is less pressure on the ground.

[image]

What is name of this type of furniture wheels?

Comment: I remember seeing/using something similar way back,but they more furniture movers(temporary), than furniture wheels and they where attached to the back/front  also.

Comment: I just need to know what this type of thing is called so I can search for it on the internet. Just using "furniture wheels" does not help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a `six wheel caster`.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=six+wheel+caster&iax=images&ia=images

[image]

image from indiamart.com

Comment: The right words in a search helps.

Comment: So these are called casters rather than wheels?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caster

Comment: "Casters" are more commonly used when there is an offset vertical axis around which they can pivot. Another possibility, depending on the precise use and whether they're to be mounted permanently, is "moving skate".

Comment: Interesting that virtually all the relevant hits are India-related. Perhaps there's something unique about Indian furniture vs. Indian floors  (and maybe a need to move said furniture easily).

Comment: Another word I'd apply here would be SKATE